# Jquery - targetting with a combination of variable and classname

Tags: jquery

I'm sure this is an easy one but I've not had to write this syntax before and i cant find an answer online!

I have a various graph sliders within a html page - each have the below code -

```
   <div class="sliderDbWk">
        <div class="spanner">
             <div class="number">
                <span class="timer"> </span>
                    <Span class="timerPc">%</Span>
             </div>
        </div>
   </div>
```

Each parent class is different (ie sliderDbMnth, sliderDbCal), i pass in to a function the sliders parent class and want to target the child .number div within this - so the parent class is stored as a variable - I'm not sure how to combine a variable and a class name in a function - i've tried below - but it doesn't work!

Any ideas?

```
 $(sliderSelect).children(' .number').css('margin-left',0);
```

Comment: What is the value of `sliderSelect`?

Comment: its the parent div class - so sliderDbWk in the above example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be `.find('.number')`, not `children('.number')` - as you start your search from '.sliderSomething' element, and `<div class="number">` is its grandchild. Quoting the doc:

> The `.children()` method differs from `.find()` in that `.children()` only
>   travels a single level down the DOM tree while `.find()` can traverse
>   down multiple levels to select descendant elements (grandchildren,
>   etc.) as well.

Answer (score 1):

If `sliderSelect` contains just the class name, you simply need to prepend it with a `.`, to turn it into a [class selector](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/):

```
$("." + sliderSelect).children(' .number').css('margin-left',0);
```

You could also remove the call to `.children()` (note that this is slightly different in that it's now looking for any descendant, rather than just direct children - this is important because in the markup you've shown, `.number` is not a direct child of the outer `div`):

```
$("." + sliderSelect + " .number").css('margin-left',0);
```